# validates_associated to validate the association between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models Post model and Comment model..First if a create a post it will have a post id of 1 then while creating a comment i can give association to the post using post_id equal to 1 but if i create a comment with post id of 2 which does not exist it would still go ahead and create a comment but with id  of **'nil'**..I want to ensure that the comment will be created only if the respective post_id is present.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments, dependent: destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  validates_associated: post
end
```

As per my understanding validates_associated checks whether the validations in post model passes before creating a comment. Clarify me if i am wrong and what would be a appropriate solution for the above scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to validate the presence of `post_id`

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  validates :post_id, :presence => true
end
```

or to validate association, you can use

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  validates_presence_of :post
end
```

Comment: `validates :post_id, presence: true` takes any value and create a comment but `validates :post, presence: true` worked fine

Answer (score 1):

First, the preferred way of setting the association b/w Post-Comment here is by :

```
def new
  @product = Product.first
  @comment = @product.comments.build
end

def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:comment][:post_id])
  @comment = @product.comments.create(comment_params)
end
```

For your particular scenario, I'm assuming that `post_id` is coming in params via some form or something, and then you wish to create a comment only if the post with that particular `post_id` exists. This can be done by adding following in `Comment` model:

```
validates :post, presence: true, allow_blank: false
```

OR

```
validate :post_presence, on: :create
def post_presence
  errors.add(:post_id, "Post doesn't exist") unless Post.find(post_id).present?
end
```

You can even do the same thing at controller-side with [`before_action`/`before_filter`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) hooks.